# Where can I find the Miracast specification?

Tags: specifications, miracast

I want to develop a Miracast application for Mac OS X. (i.e. something to display imagery to a miracast-enabled device) The only problem I'm having right now is that I can't find the official specification for this.

Is it possible that you need to be a member of the wi-fi alliance to get this specification? Is this even an open standard?

Or better: Is there a (open-source) miracast library I can use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you seen this? http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/openwfd/

As for the wi-fi alliance, you don't need to be a member but it will cost you $199: https://www.wi-fi.org/wi-fi-display-technical-specification-v11

Comment: Can't believe I didn't find openwfd by myself. This is a really useful library! Now I have a starting point at least, thanks!

Comment: Hello Tovi,
were you able to compile openwfd/miracle on osx? I'm stuck on libsystemd/libudev. I am using mac ports.

Comment: They've since updated the link, it's now https://www.wi-fi.org/file/wi-fi-display-technical-specification-v11 (but it's free after registration)

Answer (score 2):

The [Wifi Display spec](https://www.wi-fi.org/wi-fi-display-technical-specification-v11) is currently free (as in 0.0$). The download still requires agreeing to a license agreement and does not seem free to redistribute.

Also, [WDS](https://github.com/01org/wds) is a new but fairly complete implementation for linux and should be easy to port to other platforms as it tries very hard to keep agnostic with respect to the stacks used to handle media playback and Wi-Fi Direct. That said, the most difficult bit in Miracast seems to be Wi-Fi Direct so if your platform does not support that well, you're pretty much out of luck...

Disclaimer: I used to work on the WDS project.

Answer (score 0):

As @Constantinos said you will have to pay 200$ for getting the specifications via wi-fi alliance.
Or, as you ask, you can look at the following implementation available on the internet:
[Java](https://github.com/adamrocker/Miracast-Sample)
or [C](https://github.com/chenbd/miracle)
I think there is enough example here to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the implementations. The java implementation seems to be bounds to Android, but the C sample could be useful. It seems to be based on OpenWFD by David Herrmann, which is what I'll be looking at (as follow-up to the answer provided by Constantinos)